# ¿Como Ejecutar Un App Que Se Encuentra Otro Directorio?

Tags: android

Como se puede ejecutar un app que no se encuentra en data/app sino en otra carpeta que sera creada por mi app donde después mi app creara el proceso de ejecución de descarga la cual descargara el .apk "Me pregunto el .apk se puede ejecutar sin instalar o se debe instalar antes". gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En breve, no, es imposible ejecutar un apk sin instalarlo.

Para instalar un apk ubicado en algún directorio público puedes usar este código:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Para poder acceder a un archivo en un directorio público es necesario que agregues este permiso al manifesto:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Nota**
La instalación del apk no es 100% automática, el usuario tendrá que aceptar explícitamente la instalación de la misma. Esto es así por cuestiones de seguridad

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo te lo agradezco .

Comment: Una pregunta este sirve para instalarlo o ejecutarlo.

Comment: Sirve para instalarlo. No se pueden ejecutar apks directamente en android.

Comment: Una pregunta cuando se ejecuta, ¿ se ejecutara o carga es el class.dex